# Alimentar variável dentro de variável

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Em JS tenho a seguinte linha:

```
var recebeMensagem = '';
var mensagemBot = '<div class="bot_mensagens">'+recebeMensagem+'</div>';
// 1ª mensagem
recebeMensagem = 'Olá';
$('.recebe_as_mensagens').append(mensagemBot);
```

Mas quando rodo esse trecho do código, não aparece a mensagem Olá dentro da DIV, ela vem vazia. Mas se no começo do código `var recebeMensagem = '';` eu já alimentar ela com Olá, aparece, como fazer da forma que estou tentando?

Pois o projeto é mais complexo, precisaria ser +- como mostrei....

Comment: Você recebe essas mensagens como?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O que você quer não corresponde ao conceito de "variável". 
Variável é um espaço de memória que será reservado para guardar valores pelo seu programa/aplicação. O que você quer talvez possa ser atingido por uma propriedade (ai estamos entrando no conceito de orientação à objeto) ou uma função.

A linguagem do javascript permite que sejam criadas funções "inline" e para o seu propósito podemos usar uma aproximação do seu código como exibido abaixo:

```js
var recebeMensagem = '';
var mensagemBot = function() {
    return '<div class="bot_mensagens">' + recebeMensagem + '</div>';
};
var conteudoHtml = '';
conteudoHtml = $('.recebe_as_mensagens').html();
recebeMensagem = 'Olá';
conteudoHtml += mensagemBot();
$('.recebe_as_mensagens').html(conteudoHtml);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="recebe_as_mensagens"></div>
```

Só ratificando, no exemplo acima, cada vez que a função `mensagemBot()` for utilizada, ela vai trazer o elemento div com o conteúdo igual a ao da variavel `recebeMensagem` no seu retorno. (Se o conteúdo da variável for alterado, o retorno da função também o será).

Answer (score 3):

Vou arriscar uma adaptação do código que pode ser o que você deseja. **Seguindo a linha da resposta do Netinho**, acredito que possa resolver. Se for isto, os créditos são do Netinho, pois apenas adaptei seu código.

```
var recebeMensagem = []

var mensagemBot = '<div class="bot_mensagens">' + recebeMensagem + '</div>';
var conteudoHtml = '';
conteudoHtml = $('.recebe_as_mensagens').html();

recebeMensagem += 'Olá';
recebeMensagem += 'Tudo bem?';
recebeMensagem += 'Tchau';

conteudoHtml += mensagemBot;
$('.recebe_as_mensagens').html(conteudoHtml);
$(".bot_mensagens").text(recebeMensagem)
```

Aqui você tem um vetor em Javascript `recebeMensagem = []`, agora basta ir jogando os itens para dentro do vetor e as mensagens serão armazenadas em posições diferentes.

Seguindo a mesma lógica, é possível varrer seu array e mostrar os resultados da seguinte forma:

```
for(var i = 0; i < recebeMensagem.length; i++){
  conteudoHtml = mensagemBot;
  $('.recebe_as_mensagens').html(conteudoHtml);
  $(".bot_mensagens").text(recebeMensagem)
}
```

> [**Veja no JsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/tiagoboeing/90qo1dmc/5/)

Espero que ajude, apenas tentei adequar a lógica, não tenho muita experiência com Javascript. Abraços!

Answer (score 3):

Você pode usar um pouco mais do ES6 se quiser deixar seu código mais fancy.

```
const outputMessage = message => `<div class="bot_mensagens">${message || 'Olá'}</div>`;
$('.recebe_as_mensagens').append(outputMessage());
$('.recebe_as_mensagens').append(outputMessage('Tc de onde?'));
```

Answer (score 2):

Você está recebendo o valor na variável `recebeMensagem` e não está a usando em nenhum lugar. Para setar o valor da variável na `div` use a função [text()](http://api.jquery.com/text/)

```js
var recebeMensagem = '';
var mensagemBot = '<div class="bot_mensagens">' + recebeMensagem + '</div>';
var conteudoHtml = '';
conteudoHtml = $('.recebe_as_mensagens').html();
recebeMensagem = 'Olá';
conteudoHtml += mensagemBot;
$('.recebe_as_mensagens').html(conteudoHtml);
$(".bot_mensagens").text(recebeMensagem)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="recebe_as_mensagens"></div>
```

Comment: Obrigado, mas desse jeito eu sei que é possível, o problema é que não posso fazer assim. A variável recebeMensagem ta lá, dentro da mensagemBot, eu teria que atualizar a mensagemBot, sem precisar reescrver ela

Comment: Pelo que entendi a solução proposta pelo Netinho não ajuda pois você está falando que ao alterar o valor de `recebeMensagem` todas as mensagens já enviadas seriam reescritas para o último valor enviado, certo? Uma dúvida, você já pensou em utilizar um vetor (array)? Pode resolver seu problema.